# Why do generators not have a 'dunder' `__send__()` method like `__next__()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Why do generators not have a 'dunder' `__send__()` method like `__next__()`?

I think that the `send()` and `next()` functions are similar. However, as you'll see in the following code, the code mixed with those functions is not aesthetically symmetrical.

```
g = some_generator()

next(g)
next(g)
g.send(some_value)
#send(g, some_value) # how about this? Is is weird? I'm wondering the reason.
```

Why doesn't Python 3 provide `__send__()` instead of `generator.send()` like `__next__()`?

Answer (score 1):

Providing `__next__` and the corresponding built-in `next` to call it makes sense because the iterator protocol is supported and used by many objects in Python.

Using `.send` is pretty much only applicable to generators from what I am aware, having it as a dunder and then creating a built-in `send` function to access that dunder just wouldn't be worth the extra hassle.